# Dropping FK Constraint On Something Other Than Name

Tags: oracle, constraints

I have a application database where there are lots of different copies of the schema on different servers (developers, stag, prod etc)

I have two tables that were related by a FK contraint like

```
Foo.fk = Bar.Id
```

I want to drop the Bar table. but I don't want to drop the Foo.fk column. I just want to remove the constraint from it.

The problem is that the script that originally created the constraint made it different in different environments. Is there a way to remove the constraint by some way other than drop by name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to drop the constraint manually:

```
DROP TABLE bar CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

will drop the bar table and any constraint referencing it.